# parse JSON file and insert data into SQL server

Tags: c#, sql, json.net

I have the following JSON object and trying to create INSERT query. What is the best method create and insert the data into database? I am using JSON.NET to parse the file. I appreciate any suggestions.

```
JsonTextReader reader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
while (reader.Read())
{
    if(reader.Value != null)
    Console.WriteLine("Field: {0}, Value: {1}", reader.TokenType, reader.Value);
}
```

Here is my JSON looks like.

```
{
  "persons": {
    "person": {
      "i_date":  "2014-03-20", 
      "i_location": "test", 
      "i_summary": "test test" 
    },
    "people": {
      "people1": {
        "first_name": "first name test1", 
        "last_name": "last name test1"  
      },
      "people2": {
        "first_name": "first name test2", 
        "last_name": "last name test2" 
      }, 
      "people3": {
        "first_name": "first name test3", 
        "last_name": "last name test3" 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Which RDBMS are we talking about? Do you want to use LINQ?

Comment: I am using SQL server. I can use LINQ. The data should go to two seperate tables. I am trying to insert Person data(i_date, i_location, i_summary) into TABLE_A and people1, people2 and people3 in TABLE_B.

Comment: That is some ugly JSON you're having to deal with. Do you have any control over the format of the incoming JSON? If you do I'd suggest changing "people" to an array of objects. Having a series of objects inside "people" each with a different name makes this much more difficult than it needs to be, unless there will always be exactly three objects under "people".

Comment: Yes. I have control over the format. There will be more than 3 (max 11) objects under "people" or less sometimes. Could you please suggest the format?

Comment: I'm still a little confused about the relationships in your data. You have persons (implying multiple) then you have a person (could there be more than one?) and under the person you have people (implying more than one people per person). It's just a very confusing relationship. If you could update your question to explain the relationships in business terms it would probably help.

Comment: There is only one "person" and many "people"(approx 11).

Comment: But the only attributes a "person" has are date, location, and summary. How is the "person" identified? And what are the "people" associated with the "person?" Is this a manager and his employees? A parent and her children? If there is only one person then why the "persons" object? Your requirements are very unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd restructure the JSON so it made more sense. You said a "person" can have multiple "people", so structure it that way. A "person" has three attributes (i.e. i_date, i_location, and i_summary) and a collection of people.

```
{
  "person":{
    "i_date":"2014-03-20",
    "i_location":"test",
    "i_summary":"test test",
    "people":[
      {
        "first_name":"first name test1",
        "last_name":"last name test1"
      },
      {
        "first_name":"first name test2",
        "last_name":"last name test2"
      },
      {
        "first_name": "first name test3",
        "last_name":"last name test3"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now you can declare some .NET classes that represent the structure.

```
public class Person2
{
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string i_date { get; set; }
    public string i_location { get; set; }
    public string i_summary { get; set; }
    public List<Person2> people { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Person person { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject to get a set of object instances.

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>( json );
```

You can now iterate over the "people" attached to the "person" and do stuff with it.

```
Console.WriteLine( root.person.i_date );
Console.WriteLine( root.person.i_location );
Console.WriteLine( root.person.i_summary );

foreach(var p in root.person.people)
{
    Console.WriteLine( p.first_name );
    Console.WriteLine( p.last_name );
}
```

At this point you can use either ADO.NET or Entity Framework to transfer the values from the objects into either SQL Parameters (ADO.NET) or EF classes to persist it into the database.

Comment: I followed the same code. I am getting myJsonObject is null. Could you please let me know what could be wrong?

Comment: Perhaps the JSON you are feeding into the call is empty. Have you tried debugging the code to make sure the string you're passing in has the correct format?

Comment: I see there is a JSON string and it is in the above format.

Comment: You also need to check for keyconstraints / duplicate keys when inserting data into subtabels